# ANDROID Get day month year from a Date (JSON) and save in variable

Tags: android, json, date

I have a problem with my Code in Android. I only want to get the date out of json.
Then I want to take this date and with them I want to make a AlarmManager. 
But the problem is, that in the variables "month year day" are some different integer values than the date really is.
Date Format is something like this: 20.04.2014

expected: 20.04.2014 but output: day=0 month=2 year=114

Do anyone see the wrong thing in my code?
Thanks :)

My Longclick Listener:

```
        listv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                           int pos, long id) {
                Object o = listv.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                JsonStrings obj= (JsonStrings)o;
                Date date=obj.ConvertToDate(obj.begin);


                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                int month = date.getMonth()-1;
                int year=date.getYear();
                int day=date.getDay();

                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
                calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);



                return true;
            }
        });
```

My JsonStrings.class:

```
public class JsonStrings {
public String name;
public String kategorie;
public String begin;
public String end;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getKategorie() {
    return kategorie;
}

public void setKategorie(String kategorie) {
    this.kategorie = kategorie;
}

public String getBegin() {
    return begin;
}

public void setBegin(String begin) {
    this.begin = begin;
}
public String getEnd() {
    return end;
}

public void setEnd(String end) {
    this.end = end;
}

public Date ConvertToDate(String date) {
    String str_date = date;
    DateFormat formatter;
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    Date newdate = null;
    try {
        newdate = (Date) formatter.parse(str_date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return newdate;
}
```

Comment: post output/expected output.

Comment: expected: 20.04.2014 but output: day=0 month=2 year=114

Comment: so year is correct, and month as well (what is `date.getMonth()-1;` supposed to do anyway?). as for day, read the documentation.

Comment: Conversation from Date to Calendar isn't required, Date has a `getTime` method that returns milliseconds in the correct time frame. What is the value of obj.begin?

Comment: obj.begin = 20.04.2014 in String out of the JSON Data

Comment: @njzk2 -1 was a wrong thing of my own because I tried sth but I delete it now. month is then 3. But day and year arent right. How can I fix this?

Comment: year and day are right. they are just not what you expect. read the documentation. really.

Comment: year thanks i got it now ;)